# xCode 9: Is it possible to switch off animation of xCode itself

Tags: xcode, xcode9

just started with xCode 9.0 and I got the feeling, that all this "nice and beautiful" animations where hints and messages moved ANIMATED in and out during editing are ... painful...

I know it's a matter of taste, however, does someone know if it is possible to switch off these animations? .. and how and where?

EDIT: As someone casted this down (without explanation), maybe an explanation from me for the reasons of that question would be useful.

Maybe I'm doing it the wrong way, but when I code I have a rough idea in my mind, write some comments to sketch the idea and start coding. Coding is an interactive process where I type very fast, think, erase and retype etc. I also copy code fragments and "repair" it on its final destination etc.. highly interactive.

Xcode needs (on big code files) roughly a second to make decisions about giving the user a hint or not. Most annoying hint in the case I'm talking here is "missing blabla ..."

When start typing an statement it is of course not finished. The sad thing: by the time Xcode has done its decision process and end the animation to roll in the hint message (1 sec decision, 1 sec animation) the statement is already completed by me.

In fact, it is often done BEFORE the animation starts - but that is another story.

Luckily during the animation of rolling in (1 sec), Xcode find out that the hint is not needed anymore (decision time of 1 sec matches the animation happening in parallel) and rolls the hint back (animation duration 1 sec).

So all time I code there is a nice "firework" of outdated hint messages rolling in and out.

Don't get me wrong I love the hint messages and all the other messages which Xcode really helps to avoid hard to find code errors.

I simply do not like this animations, as they use one wasted second every time they appear. This is a nice feature for presentations (e.g. WWDC talks), but in day by day fast coding mode, they are not useful.

So I look for a way to switch just the animation off.

Thanks a lot in advance

Hardy